# get a common value from multiple tables using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Below is my values in each table

Reading - Table name

student_id - student ID

```
1
4
5
7
6
9
11
```

speaking -  table

```
9
10
12
13
14
15
```

writing - table

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
9
```

Listening - table

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

My query will return the student_id's which is common in 4 tables . for example
my query will return for this example is

only 9 'id is common for all tables so the query will return the count as 1.
I tried with inner join and some distinct way of queries but in result I'm getting wrong answer.Please anyone help me to get out of this issue.Thanks in advance.

Comment: mysql or sql-server Make your choice.

Comment: Can you add expected output as well please?

Comment: I Want the count of common id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select count(distinct a.student_id)

from reading_table a

join speaking_table b
on a.student_id=b.student_id

join writing_table c
on b.student_id=c.student_id

join listening_table d
on c.student_id=d.student_id

Answer (score 2):

Use `INTERSECT`

```
select count(1) 
from 
(
select student_id from Reading
INTERSECT 
select student_id from speaking 
INTERSECT 
..
) a
```

If `student_id` is duplicated in any of these tables and if you don't want to count the duplicates then

```
select count(Distinct student_id) 
from 
(
select student_id from Reading
INTERSECT 
select student_id from speaking 
INTERSECT 
..
) a
```

Comment: @Chanukya - Yep.. Nothing much to do in new company :D

Comment: select count(Distinct student_id) 
from 
(
select student_id from reading_answers
INTERSECT 
select student_id from listening_answers 
INTERSECT 
select student_id from writing_answers
INTERSECT 
select student_id from speaking_answers
) reading_answers;.  check whether it is right or not

Comment: @KavyaShree - That is perfectly right. Which DBMS you are using ?

Comment: @KavyaShree - What is the error you are getting ? I think `Mysql` does not support `Intersect`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.id FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
INNER JOIN table3 AS t3 ON t1.id = t3.id
INNER JOIN table4 AS t4 ON t1.id = t4.id
```

This will return the id's that are common within all 4 tables.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `INNER JOIN` with `COUNT DISTINCT` will do:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT studentID)
FROM Student AS st
INNER JOIN Speaking AS s ON st.studentID = s.studentID
INNER JOIN Writing AS w ON s.studentID = w.studentID
INNER JOIN Listening AS l ON w.studentID = l.studentID
```